# How to render qcc plots to HTML using RMarkdown and knitr

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown, qcc

First SO question so please go easy.

I am running the qcc package with Rstudio and I would like to create a report on the graphs that I am generating. I have no problem generating the graphs and exporting each individual graph to pdf for example. I also have no problem creating a HTML document with RMarkdown and Knitr with other plots.
However, with qcc package, I cannot do this! Hopefully someone out there has had this issue and solved.

Here is example from ?qcc that can be used in an RMarkdown file with the issue I am seeing:

```
data(pistonrings)
attach(pistonrings)
diameter <- qcc.groups(diameter, sample)

    qcc(diameter[1:25,], type="xbar")
    qcc(diameter[1:25,], type="xbar", newdata=diameter[26:40,])
    q <- qcc(diameter[1:25,], type="xbar", newdata=diameter[26:40,], plot=FALSE)
    plot(q, chart.all=FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: Works fine for me just as you've listed it, and when knit to HTML creates a number of copies of the control chart. I am using knitr 1.17, r markdown 1.8, and r studio 1.1.383

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Stewart. See my answer below for the answer to my problem.

Comment: Any idea how to suppress to one copy in Knitr?

Comment: Hi Todd, i don't fully understand your question, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the reason for this eventually. When function `dev.off()` is called in the Rmarkdown file then the base plot function will not work!...I didn't include the `dev.off()` in my question as it was at the top of my script and I hadn't spotted it.

Sorry for the confusion and I  hope this helps somebody else.